# How to send a JSON response from an API route in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, next.js

I am developing a tiny REST API for a Next.js app. If I place my `route.ts` in rootDir -> app -> api -> hello -> route.ts that looks like this, then it works:

```js
//route.ts
export async function GET(request: Request) {
  return new Response('Hello, Next.js!')
}
```

I can make a successful GET request via Postman to localhost:3000/api/hello.

I change the code now to the following:

```js
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export async function GET(request: NextApiRequest, response: NextApiResponse) {
  return response.json({ message: "Hello, Next.js!" });
}
```

Now it fails and I get the error message:

```
error TypeError: response.json is not a function
```

The issue is known but the upgrade to the latest lts or the latest node version does not fix my problem: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48524.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While your attempt would work in the [`pages`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) directory of Next.js, the initial way of setting up routes, with the newer [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) folder you need to use the `NextResponse` object from `next/server`, as you can read on the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers):

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  return NextResponse.json({ messsage: "Hello World" });
}
```